# Which datatype to choose and how to implement it on the script (Many-to-Many relationship)

Tags: php, database, database-design

I have a form where the user must select a large number of facilities using checkboxes. I am thinking to save each checkbox as a ENUM('0','1') datatype is the facilities_table and then display them in my view like this:

```
<?php
   $jacuzzi =  $facilities['jacuzzi'] == 1?"jacuzzi available":"jacuzzi not available";
?>
```

I wonder if this is the best way...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could be OK for small amounts of large.

Comment: @Jan I find your comment to be unintelligible. "[...] small amounts of large." Large what?

Comment: Exactly :) OP was not really clear on that part ... Hence my snarky comment :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually use a TINYINT(1) column with the following definition:

```
`MyBooleanColumn` TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0
```

I'm not aware if there is any sort of performance benefit to this, but It would allow you to do more than 2 values, it could be likely up to 255 as TINYINT is a byte. But I imagine that an ENUM field requires more than one byte.

That said, if you're trying to link up multiple `facilities` with multiple `users` then perhaps something like this is in order?

```
CREATE TABLE `facilities_users` (
  `facility_id` BIGINT() UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'foreign key -> facilities.id',
  `user_id` BIGINT() UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'foreign key -> users.id',
)
```

With the above table you can just join and get a list of facilities the user would like to have. You don't even need to store a boolean value because the fact that a row in this table exists with the facility id linking it to a user means they chose it.

Comment: I can't understand how to use this table structure in a crud application. Specifically on update/delete actions. What if I the user updates 60 facilities (check/uncheck). I have to make 60 queries to the db?

Comment: You can do a multiple insert instead of 60 queries. `INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);` And if they "uncheck" something you can then do: `DELETE FROM facilities_users WHERE facility_id IN (2,5,6,...) AND user_id = 7;` See [this resource for a way to do that with PHP arrays](http://data.agaric.com/node/1930#comment-1876).

Comment: what if the facility_id/user_id combination already exists in the db when I do the INSERT?

Comment: You can put a primary key on that combination and prevent duplicate rows with that. It'll just error out on that insert. I can't speak on how that would affect a multiple insert statement though.

Answer (score 1):

If your database supports it, I'd suggest using the `BOOLEAN` data type.

If this is MySQL:

> BOOL, BOOLEAN
>
> These types are synonyms for TINYINT(1). A value of zero is considered false. Nonzero values are considered true:

-- [Numeric Types Overview](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a user table and a facility table then you must save this in the user_facility table just to keep everything normalized.

Comment: So you suggest a third table for reference?

Comment: I imagine it's some kind of real estate that has the facilities. Also, if there are, say, 10 facilities, it's quite ok to store them as separate fields.

Comment: How can I use this table in a crud system?

Comment: @chchrist - use the database like you should and create a facility table where you will store names. If you only store Ids you will have  a hard time keeping track of them. Regarding the crud system, it's just like any other table. You will make one insert with the id of the user and the id of the facility ( don't forget the autoincrement column )